# When to use custom collection name

Tags: magento

In Magento, i know that you can do the following to get collections:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('module/model_collection');
```

and

```
Mage::getModel('module/model)->getCollection();
```

This all comes from the fact that you can provide your own custom name for collection

for example: `Mage::getResourceModel('module/model_blahblahblah');`

so `getCollection` will automatically find that for you.

My question is when would you actually want to use 'blahblahblah' instead of 'collection'

Answer (score 1):

The difference between 'normal' resource model and collection are:

- 'normal' resource model -> extends from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` (for flat type, version 1.6.0.0 ++). It is mainly used to connect with your database, such as get data / saving data to database
- collection -> extends from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` (for flat type). It is mainly used to get 'LIST' of your data. e.g. : get list of orders

So for your question: when would you actually want to use 'blahblahblah' instead of 'collection'

There is no exact answer for that. It is not a must to use name `collection` to get the list of data. You can use `blahblahblah` if you want but of course it is better to stick to the convention (Magento's way).

Naming it as collection will give 'normal' people a picture that it is related with collection (collection usually related with list, in our case it is a list of data / object / etc). What will happen if they see: `Mage::getResourceModel('module/model_blahblahblah');` maybe `blahblahblah` is too weird to understandable by other people (though the name won't be as extreme as `blahblahblah`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your collection class:
 `Namespace_Module_Model_Mysql4_Module_Collection`

 to
 `Namespace_Module_Model_Mysql4_Module_Blahblahblah` 
then you can use `Mage::getResourceModel('module/model_blahblahblah')` method for getting collection.
Was that helpful?

Comment: No sorry, i am asking, when it would be useful/correct to not use _collection and instead _blahblahblah

Comment: Since there is one collection class per module so i don't thin there is such case where you need to change the collection name.

Comment: Why would magento allow it to be customised then?

Comment: Martin: all collections are resource models, but not all resource models are collections. Let that sink in for a minute :)